# Как отключить мультитач на виджете

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Есть виджет, к примеру `Container`, child-ом которого является `Listview`, `builder` которого возвращает `Dismissible`, с удалением данного элемента при свайпе. Если одновременно выбрать 2 или более элементов данного `Listview` и свайпнуть их, они оба удалятся. Есть ли возможность избежать удаление нескольких выбранных элементов? Или, как вариант, не обрабатывать второе касание на экран. Спасибо!

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final items = List<String>.generate(10, (i) => "Item ${i + 1}");

  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _handleDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails update) {
      //code is here
      print("drag update");
    }

    void _handleDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
      //code is here
      print("drag end");
    }

    Drag _handleOnStart(Offset position) {
      if (count < 1) {
        setState(() {
          count++;
        });
        return _DragHandler(_handleDragUpdate, _handleDragEnd);
      }
      return null;
    }

    setState(() {
      count = 0;
    });

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hover Example'),
        ),
        body: RawGestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
            ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
              () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
              (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                instance..onStart = _handleOnStart;
              },
            ),
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = items[index];
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(item),
                  confirmDismiss: (_) {
                    print("Dismissed $item");
                  },
                  background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                  child: ListTile(title: Text('$item')),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class _DragHandler extends Drag {
  _DragHandler(this.onUpdate, this.onEnd);

  final GestureDragUpdateCallback onUpdate;
  final GestureDragEndCallback onEnd;

  @override
  void update(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    onUpdate(details);
  }

  @override
  void end(DragEndDetails details) {
    onEnd(details);
  }

  @override
  void cancel() {}
}
```

Comment: А можно код предоставить?

Comment: @MiT предоставил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использовния необходимо создать инстанс `OnlyOnePointerRecognizerWidget` и передавать в него любой виджет, как child.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class OnlyOnePointerRecognizer extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {
  int _p = 0;
  @override
  void addPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    startTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    if (_p == 0) {
      resolve(GestureDisposition.rejected);
      _p = event.pointer;
    } else {
      resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    }
  }

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'only one pointer recognizer';

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if (!event.down && event.pointer == _p) {
      _p = 0;
    }
  }
}

class OnlyOnePointerRecognizerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  OnlyOnePointerRecognizerWidget({this.child});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
        OnlyOnePointerRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<OnlyOnePointerRecognizer>(
          () => OnlyOnePointerRecognizer(),
          (OnlyOnePointerRecognizer instance) {},
        ),
      },
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```